# How to fix 'There was a problem with the requested skill's response' error in Alexa

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I'm trying to build a skill that decides whether you should wear shorts that day or not, but keep getting the error as described in the title. There have been many other posts about this but none seem to have an answer that works.

I've tried switching runtime to node 8.10 and back to 10.X but nothing seems to work.

I know the API key is hashes. It isn't in my actual code.

```
/* eslint-disable  no-console */

const Alexa = require('ask-sdk-core');
const cookbook = require('./alexa-cookbook.js');
const request = require('request');
require('dotenv').config();

let apiKey = '###################';
let city = 'leeds'
let url = `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=${city}&units=metric&appid=${apiKey}`

//=========================================================================================================================================
//TODO: The items below this comment need your attention.
//=========================================================================================================================================

const SKILL_NAME = 'Should I Wear Shorts';
const HELP_MESSAGE = 'You can say should I wear shorts, or, you can say exit... What can I help you with?';
const HELP_REPROMPT = 'What can I help you with?';
const FALLBACK_MESSAGE = 'The Should I Wear Shorts skill can\'t help you with that. What can I help you with?';
const FALLBACK_REPROMPT = 'What can I help you with?';
const STOP_MESSAGE = 'Goodbye!';

const yesSpeech = ['Yes, you should definitely wear shorts!'];
const noSpeech = ['No, you should not wear shorts today!'];

//=========================================================================================================================================
//Editing anything below this line might break your skill.
//=========================================================================================================================================

function getAnswer() {
  request(url, function (err, response, body) {
       if (err){
           console.log('error', err);
       }
       else{
           console.log('body:', body);
           const weather = JSON.parse(body);
       }
   });
   if(weather.main.temp < 20){
       return true;
   }
   else{
       return false;
   }
}

const GetAnswerHandler = {
  canHandle(handlerInput) {
    const request = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request;
    return request.type === 'LaunchRequest'
      || (request.type === 'IntentRequest'
        && request.intent.name === 'GetAnswerIntent');
  },
  handle(handlerInput) {
    if(getAnswer()){
      const speechOutput = yesSpeech[Math.floor(Math.random() * yesSpeech.length)];
    }
    else {
      const speechOutput = noSpeech[Math.floor(Math.random() * noSpeech.length)];
    }

    return handlerInput.responseBuilder
      .speak(speechOutput)
      .getResponse();
  },
};

const HelpHandler = {
  canHandle(handlerInput) {
    const request = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request;
    return request.type === 'IntentRequest'
      && request.intent.name === 'AMAZON.HelpIntent';
  },
  handle(handlerInput) {
    return handlerInput.responseBuilder
      .speak(HELP_MESSAGE)
      .reprompt(HELP_REPROMPT)
      .getResponse();
  },
};

const FallbackHandler = {
  // 2018-May-01: AMAZON.FallbackIntent is only currently available in en-US locale.
  //              This handler will not be triggered except in that locale, so it can be
  //              safely deployed for any locale.
  canHandle(handlerInput) {
    const request = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request;
    return request.type === 'IntentRequest'
      && request.intent.name === 'AMAZON.FallbackIntent';
  },
  handle(handlerInput) {
    return handlerInput.responseBuilder
      .speak(FALLBACK_MESSAGE)
      .reprompt(FALLBACK_REPROMPT)
      .getResponse();
  },
};

const ExitHandler = {
  canHandle(handlerInput) {
    const request = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request;
    return request.type === 'IntentRequest'
      && (request.intent.name === 'AMAZON.CancelIntent'
        || request.intent.name === 'AMAZON.StopIntent');
  },
  handle(handlerInput) {
    return handlerInput.responseBuilder
      .speak(STOP_MESSAGE)
      .getResponse();
  },
};

const SessionEndedRequestHandler = {
  canHandle(handlerInput) {
    const request = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request;
    return request.type === 'SessionEndedRequest';
  },
  handle(handlerInput) {
    console.log(`Session ended with reason: ${handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.reason}`);

    return handlerInput.responseBuilder.getResponse();
  },
};

const ErrorHandler = {
  canHandle() {
    return true;
  },
  handle(handlerInput, error) {
    console.log(`Error handled: ${error.message}`);

    return handlerInput.responseBuilder
      .speak('Sorry, an error occurred.')
      .reprompt('Sorry, an error occurred.')
      .getResponse();
  },
};

const skillBuilder = Alexa.SkillBuilders.custom();

exports.handler = skillBuilder
  .addRequestHandlers(
    GetAnswerHandler,
    HelpHandler,
    ExitHandler,
    FallbackHandler,
    SessionEndedRequestHandler
  )
  .addErrorHandlers(ErrorHandler)
  .lambda();
```

I'd expect the output to be yes or no, but as I've said it just says 'There was a problem with the requested skill's response.'

JSON Input:

```
    "version": "1.0",
    "session": {
        "new": false,
        "sessionId": "amzn1.echo-api.session.eaf07559-9dca-44b4-bff0-a64aedde4f54",
        "application": {
            "applicationId": "amzn1.ask.skill.4609edff-de26-47de-b3bf-aa2f894b841d"
        },
        "user": {
            "userId": "amzn1.ask.account.AEL3JJK2BVA6K3EVV2T7LBQJS4VROUS22B7P4BWODLXENSNJBCNIH62ECVZ7HSSECCEUAEJ6GYSMLTMBWWFG45C3LQCMNSSET4LCMD7C64SOSZZBNTG7AOZL27J2FFLOH7FPNDFCULOLST3QXOR2GGTC57ZP7A5K5KOIWCSRJY4L6AGSUKOSXEFHVWPAN4MIIAWAGVRPJYQWUNA"
        }
    },
    "context": {
        "System": {
            "application": {
                "applicationId": "amzn1.ask.skill.4609edff-de26-47de-b3bf-aa2f894b841d"
            },
            "user": {
                "userId": "amzn1.ask.account.AEL3JJK2BVA6K3EVV2T7LBQJS4VROUS22B7P4BWODLXENSNJBCNIH62ECVZ7HSSECCEUAEJ6GYSMLTMBWWFG45C3LQCMNSSET4LCMD7C64SOSZZBNTG7AOZL27J2FFLOH7FPNDFCULOLST3QXOR2GGTC57ZP7A5K5KOIWCSRJY4L6AGSUKOSXEFHVWPAN4MIIAWAGVRPJYQWUNA"
            },
            "device": {
                "deviceId": "amzn1.ask.device.AF65CFND4RS4FFXCS7WVYUH3KMTDFQY7BJMKJUCG6VESIFV6HMWPKAYDVYM6UNE3ZF3JN4DXLL4BU33T7DAYJB574KAJL6RXCYD62EMGFLLAQYHQ6KYIW2CIVNGY3MKV5IA64H6OYGZXSDID2AG2N36FEBPHNKKP65A3WIMXGSX3UPBESI4BM",
                "supportedInterfaces": {}
            },
            "apiEndpoint": "https://api.eu.amazonalexa.com",
            "apiAccessToken": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjEifQ.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.LknWDy50k4NtjIi_n0MxWbFEN-tYpLOOJlj3-NTV-wNch5qXU_P9ZK0e85Az80pxWV9atVOphpHppVgYN9vmzMlyjZih-tBUDEznjhEjhUlL3Up5OyKHvnIz75EzJD7iRbeGcluSQI1CKiXhWm-_RUz8aTpYkU9kOy2Ensk6m0U0IY3uWLvd7PBAfSHIzZi3wpXJVncmvGBS8q_wQRgxkmFVAXEq5Mw2nFzl1tj0pJ33tyW_w6y93Xk62UrtNAue3c1299VLpnplrDmcPd82EpE-1bSQj1ZJzDEj_IaSmiwmn3CH9CUmh8rwomPYn6BvURma-zckhiW94ZI_0XeXNw"
        },
        "Viewport": {
            "experiences": [
                {
                    "arcMinuteWidth": 246,
                    "arcMinuteHeight": 144,
                    "canRotate": false,
                    "canResize": false
                }
            ],
            "shape": "RECTANGLE",
            "pixelWidth": 1024,
            "pixelHeight": 600,
            "dpi": 160,
            "currentPixelWidth": 1024,
            "currentPixelHeight": 600,
            "touch": [
                "SINGLE"
            ],
            "video": {
                "codecs": [
                    "H_264_42",
                    "H_264_41"
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    "request": {
        "type": "SessionEndedRequest",
        "requestId": "amzn1.echo-api.request.c36a55a7-cf3f-4840-ad96-85f1779fb4fc",
        "timestamp": "2019-08-29T06:58:01Z",
        "locale": "en-GB",
        "reason": "ERROR",
        "error": {
            "type": "INVALID_RESPONSE",
            "message": "An exception occurred while dispatching the request to the skill."
        }
    }
}
```

The JSON Output is blank.

Comment: Have you looked into your Lamda cloudwatch logs?

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: It could be your `const speechOutput = ...`. `const` is [block scope](https://medium.com/@josephcardillo/the-difference-between-function-and-block-scope-in-javascript-4296b2322abe) so `.speak(speechOutput)` won't have access to that variable. You could use `let speechOutput` before the if statement (which would be in scope), then set the value.